# JAVA: change element type

Tags: java

I am brand new in JAVA, and I didn't understand the line talking about "Item temp = (Item)obj;". What does the "(Item)" mean? Does it force to change type of obj? Please help me to figure it out, thanks!

```
public class Item implements Comparable {
    private String id;
    private String name;
    private double retail;
    private int quantity;
    private double price;

    Item(String idIn, String nameIn, String retailIn, String quanIn) {
        id = idIn;
        name = nameIn;
        retail = Double.parseDouble(retailIn);
        quantity = Integer.parseInt(quanIn);

        if (quantity > 400)
            price = retail * .5D;
        else if (quantity > 200)
            price = retail * .6D;
        else
            price = retail * .7D;
        price = Math.floor( price * 100 + .5 ) / 100;
    }

    public int compareTo(Object obj) {
        Item temp = (Item)obj;
        if (this.price < temp.price)
            return 1;
        else if (this.price > temp.price)
            return -1;
        return 0;
    }
    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public double getRetail() {
        return retail;
    }
    public int getQuantity() {
        return quantity;
    }
    public double getPrice() {
        return price;
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, you are right. It is called type conversion

Answer (score 2):

`Item temp = (Item)obj;` is performing [type conversion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_conversion) (or *typecasting*) `Object obj` to the type `Item`. If `obj` is not an `Item`, then it will throw a [`ClassCastException`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/ClassCastException.html), the Javadoc of which says (in part)

> Thrown to indicate that the code has attempted to cast an object to a subclass of which it is not an instance. For example, the following code generates a `ClassCastException`:
>
> ```
> Object x = new Integer(0);
> System.out.println((String)x);
> ```

However, because `Comparable` is generic, it's also possible to make `Item` like

```
public class Item implements Comparable<Item>
```

and then `compareTo(Item)` like

```
@Override
public int compareTo(Item temp) {
    return Double.compare(this.price, temp.price);
    // if (this.price < temp.price)
    //     return 1;
    // else if (this.price > temp.price)
    //     return -1;
    // return 0;
}
```

Comment: @EricHsieh If this answer your question, you should consider accepting the answer.

Answer (score 0):

This line: Item temp = (Item)obj;
Taking another object of this class for comparing. This is for sorting of group/list of item class objects.
So When we will sort list of Item, It will take this(current) object with the passing object of this class.

Answer (score 0):

This is known as the casting(Genrally its categorised in two type Down & Up Casting).
Casting allows the use of generic programming in Java, 
where code is written to work with all objects of classes descended from some base class (often java.lang.Object, for utility classes). 
However, the use of casting causes a unique set of problems.If you try to cast two object which doesn't share same type hierarchy,
 i.e. there is no parent child relationship between them, you will get compile time error.On the other hand if you type cast objects from same type hierarchy butthe object which you are casting are not of the same type on which you are casting then it will throw ClassCastException in Java.

And @Elliot have already explained it by example

Comment: `Casting allows the use of generic programming in Java`: This is never the primary reason for casting.  And, the explanation of the compile-time error is not very accurate either.

Comment: @AdrianShum yes its right Generic Progamming is not the primary reason of Object Casting but its fall in one of the reason.
If Base and Derived class are not related to each other and doesn't part of same type hierarchy, 
cast will throw compile time error. for example you can not cast String and StringBuffer, as they are not from same type hierarchy.

Comment: Given 1. Casting appear before Generics is available in Java 2. There is nothing related to Generics in this question, 3. Generic programming is never be the main reason for casting (Actually proper generic programming should greatly reduce the need for casting), sorry that I cannot consider your answer to be appropriate.   Second, for the compile time error, here is what you said in your original answer: " *If you try to cast two object...* " So, you can see why I said explanation was "not accurate"?